# How to make ball bounce off of triangle in Py.Processing?

Tags: python, processing, pong

Im building a game in processing python. It is similar to pong except the paddles can rotate thus changing the direction of the ball. There is also supposed to be a feature where if you hit a smaller ball, triangles pop up on each the top and botton making it harder to get the ball through to the other side. So the ball is supposed to bounce off of the triangle and and make a 45 degree angle in reference to the x and y axels. Im having a hard time solving this problem. [picture of game, white circle is the ball that I that is supposed to bounce on the triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTtuy.png). My initial thought was to make an if statement containing two mx + c functions as follows.

if triangle_score == 1 and ball_y >= (ball_x * -1) + 350 and ball_y >= (ball_x - 450):
ball_dx = ball_dx * -1
ball_dy = ball_dy * -1

Needless to say it didn't work very well. Does anyone know processing. Would be sooo thankful for any help I can get.

Comment: The [tag:pygame] tag is for questions about [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news)

Comment: Also, remember to reduce your problem to _just_ your problem. Run through the [mcve] execise (which is by far more for you than for us: most of the time simply trying to create a good MCVE lets you find the actual problem without ever needing help from someone else, but you _do_ need to go through it. And if you're still stuck, you now have perfect code to put in a post). And then of course remember to write [a proper post](/help/how-to-ask) using [proper markup](/markdown).